# Quick Launch not visible in extended site

Tags: 2007, quick-launch

I have enabled quick Launch for a wiki site. This works fine for the base site but it is not visible in Extended site.

What are the possible reasons for this?

I created another wiki site and enabled quick launch and this is visble in both the sites (base and extended) but not sure why I am having issu with the above site.